# No Dagger2 generated files for JUnit tests

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

A new AndroidStudio 1.1 version introduced the unit testing support. This URL http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support provides step-by-step instruction how to setup IDE to run JUnit tests for Android sources.

This plugin https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt used to provide Dagger2 generated files to AS and it works OK for usual Android code but unfortunately there is no generated Dagger2 files for any JUnit test class. I tried to configure dependency like

`androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'`

according to android-apt plugin documentation but without success.

I think the problem is in different sources directory for Unit tests - it's `src/test/java` instead of `src/androidTest/java` that used by android instrumentation tests.

Can you please provide any help or info how to resolve this trouble?

Comment: You should open a dagger 2 ticket.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I already opened ticket #125 on the Dagger 2 GitHub project, three days ago. Silence at this moment. And contacted with Hugo Visser, the author of android-apt plugin. He asked for sample project to check the issue. No more info already.

Answer (score 4):

Having

```
// You version may vary
androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

in your dependencies, open a terminal in your project, run

```
./gradlew assembleTest
```

This will generate the Dagger component classes living under your androidTest source set.

Go back to Android Studio, the class now exists and can be used.

Comment: Alternatively to open console you can go in Gradle pane (top-right corner there is a "Gradle" text, click to open) -> your app -> AssembleAndroidTest